# How do I add, delete or modify a flow using opendaylight?

Tags: opendaylight

I have set up an SDN using Open vSwitch and OpenDaylight.

I have two machines with Ubuntu and I am using KVM to simulate two devices (for now). I have two other devices in the network. The OpenDaylight Dlux network topology shows an openflow switch and five hosts - the two virtual devices, two real devices and the one machine; the other machine is the one that has ovs and odl and the KVMs.

Now I want to play with flow control... From one of the virtual devices, I can ping the other host/machine - traffic flows from the host through the openflow switch. I am working on setting up a samba server so that I will be able to wget a file from that machine. BUT ultimately, I want to change the flow, so that when I try to download the file, it will instead go from the host through one of the real devices.

I am having trouble locating relevant documentation about how to add/modify/delete a flow using opendaylight (that I can understand). Maybe that last part is the actual problem, but thought I would ask here for some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play with flow you have to use opendaylight openflow plugin here the user guide link
http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/openflow-plugin-project-user-guide.html

you can install postman and send the request to the openflow plugin,,, you can change flow on each port , QOS, flow timeout, ..etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I still do not understand. I am looking in the specified user guide, under Programmatic Interface, as I am trying to automate add, delete or modify a flow (from DLUX app, based on user entered info). I have no clue how to code it. All I see in this user guide is about using POSTMAN. If I follow the link in the user guide, •Models Documentation (OpenFlow Services Section), it just leads me to MD-SAL Model Reference and I don't know what to look for in there. No examples anywhere. Any further information you could provide would be greatly appreciated!